# While trying to run cryptocode I get the error: "module 'hashlib' has no attribute 'scrypt'"

Tags: python, cryptography, hashlib

As I mentioned in the title Im trying to run the library cryptocode by using this simple code:

```
import cryptocode

password = "This is a test"
key = "My Key"


def encrypt(password, key):
    return cryptocode.encrypt(password, key)


def decrypt(encryptetpass):
    return cryptocode.decrypt(encryptetpass, key)


encrypted_pass = encrypt(password, key)
print(encrypted_pass)

print(decrypt(encrypted_pass))
```

While running it locally on Windows I get no errors, but trying the same on Linux generates me the previously in the title mentioned error:

```
(venv) pwd$ python3.9 crypt_test.py

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/crypt_test.py", line 15, in <module>
    encrypted_pass = encrypt(password, key)
  File "/crypt_test.py", line 8, in encrypt
    return cryptocode.encrypt(password, key)
  File "/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cryptocode/myfunctions.py", line 16, in encrypt
    private_key = hashlib.scrypt(
AttributeError: module 'hashlib' has no attribute 'scrypt'
```

I tried updating Openssl, reinstalled my venv and Python.

Comment: Please, post the full traceback you get along with [mre] that produce the error

Comment: Also, what version of python do you use? Is it possible that on Linux you use python version before 3.6 or even python2?

Comment: @buran, I did the edit. As you can see, Im using Python3.9.

Comment: `hashlib.scrypt` notes that it requires OpenSSL 1.1+, sounds like your Linux build of Python was built with some other version of OpenSSL

Answer (score 1):

**check below points:**

To check which all versions are installed

> which python

```
//use python or python3 as per your needs
```

To check where all versions are installed

> where python

```
//use python or python3 as per your needs
```

In mycase i was having two paths as below,

```
/usr/bin/python 
/usr/local/bin/python
```

so, now check VS Code,

- Command + Shipt + P
- Search/Select Python Interpreter
- select appropriate version you are using, if not listed Add the respective path and select the same.

This Solution worked for me:)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to build the latest OpenSSL?  I see instructions here:  https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/how-to-install-openssl-from-source-on-linux/
(wasn't able to try this because I'm not running Linux).  Please let us know if this worked.